# How do i make an image appear larger when clicked on in Salesforce landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I am trying to make an image on my salesforce landing page larger once clicked on. i hope you can help me? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845496/change-image-size-when-clicking-on-it-in-javascript

In the link above is a javascript solution to a very similar use case